# Opposite of 'I put up the umbrella'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idioms, vocabulary

We say: She put up the umbrella.

Can I say: When it stopped raining, she put down the umbrella.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

"Put down" means "placed on the floor, or on a table (or similar)". A teacher may say "put down your pencil" at the end of a test.

Instead you could say "closed her umbrella", or "folded her umbrella". I would also probably say that she "opened her umbrella" (but "put up" is quite clear). If you need an exact analogue to "put up" then use "take down".

("Put down" also means to insult, and for a vet to kill a sick animal so it has quite a range of meanings)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's correct. You can also say: "...she folded up the umbrella".

Comment: You can put your foot down, put your pencil down at the end of a test, plead for someone to put down the gun, but "put down the umbrella" does not give the same impression as she "closed" or "folded" the umbrella.

Comment: Thank your for your remark. I was sure that these two words mean the same as it was given in a thick English-Russian dictionary.

Comment: It might help people understand your answer better if you include what you found in the dictionary. If I put down my umbrella, I probably mean I set my umbrella on a table or the floor (removed it from my hands), not "closed" it because it was open.

Comment: take down a tent

Comment: @ ColleenV: Please see the section *Словосочетания* (I don't usually use this online dictionary though): http://wooordhunt.ru/word/umbrella

Comment: Yulia, you don't need to convince me, I'm just offering a suggestion that I hope might cause people to upvote your answer. If you added some explanation of why it's correct, I think it would improve your answer.